# Angular - Code to trigger only first time Load

Tags: angular

I've created a skeleton structure for my app in Angular 9. The skeleton code initializes in  `ngAfterViewInit()` hook.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.showSpinner = false;  
     this.interval = setInterval(() => {  
       this.domLoaded = true;
     }, 5000);
}
```

But every time I load this page (or come again after navigating from any other route) it still Fires the event to show the skeleton. I want the skeleton only show on the first Load of app.

I have also used `ngAfterContentInit()` but that didn't work

Comment: IDK why you only want first time instead you should need to show whenever content not gets loaded. anyways for the first time you can set some value in web storage and then make a check accordingly

Comment: I'm using Nastaleeq Fonts, the other structure is simple and loads fast but the fonts took time, for this purpose I used the skeleton technique. And once the fonts loaded, then it goes smooth that is why I was thinking on to use this only the first time load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to go about with this (also, I do agree with the comment by Pardeep - you should look for other ways) but sticking to your question, try to save the state within localStorage/sessionStorage so that the information is not lost after navigating to other pages in your site. So something like this will work:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.showSpinner = false; 
  if (!sessionStorage.getItem('siteInit')) {  
   this.interval = setInterval(() => {  
    this.domLoaded = true;
    sessionStorage.setItem('siteInit', 'true');
   }, 5000);
  } else {
   this.domLoaded = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: It sets the session variable for the first time, but returning on this page again doesn't work and the page just shows loading... even the session value can be seen in the console

Comment: @user54226 Ah sorry about that, seems like my code didn't set domLoaded to true, I have updated the code. Can you try again

Answer (score 0):

The `ngAfterViewInit()`lifecycle hook gets called every time, your component is loaded. To achieve your required functionality you could use a [Singleton Service](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services) and set the `domLoaded` property there.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you placed `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in `app.component.ts`, this component will only load once and the subsequent navigation will happen within the application (Single Page Application benefits).

Therefore, you can run the code right there if this is what you need.

If you want to only run the code once the first time a user accesses your page and not run it for subsequent **refreshes**, you can use the browser Local Storage to keep track of the state (mark if it's the first time accessing the page or not). Then you'd need to check on every page load whether you need to run the code or not.

**Strictly related to your question**, if you're tracking the state of a `spinner`, you most likely want it to run on every page refresh. For this you can hold its state in a [Service](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services) instead of Local Storage.

*Side note*: Accessing browser's Local Storage is much more inefficient than accessing a variable that's already in memory.